# Unrecognized keyword arguments: 'use_multiprocessing' in Keras Gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try to fit the below model:

```
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    validation_data=[X_test, y_test],
                    batch_size=50,
                    epochs=100,
                    use_multiprocessing=True, 
                    workers=8,
                    verbose=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-f5dcd501cd38> in <module>
     17                 use_multiprocessing=True,
     18                 workers=8,
---> 19                 verbose=1)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    940             epochs = kwargs.pop('nb_epoch')
    941         if kwargs:
--> 942             raise TypeError('Unrecognized keyword arguments: ' + str(kwargs))
    943         if x is None and y is None and steps_per_epoch is None:
    944             raise ValueError('If fitting from data tensors, '

TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'use_multiprocessing': True, 'workers': 8}
```

Are `use_multiprocessing` and `workers` not available in `keras-gpu`? They're in the docs. I can't find any mention of this problem online. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of keras are you using? Note that keras-gpu is not one of the officially supported keras packages.

Comment: Keras version '2.3.1'

Comment: Also when I press shift + tab in jupyter, these arguments are not listed.

Comment: How did you determine the version? Import keras and print keras.__version__

Comment: @matias yes that's right

Comment: I don't think you have Keras 2.3.1, you probably have a much older version (< 1.x), as I cannot reproduce your problem in 2.3.1, and I can see those parameters in the 2.3.1 tree https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.3.1/keras/engine/training.py#L1584

Comment: Also note that there is no official package called keras-gpu, you are using some unofficial version, make sure you are using the official wheel from pip. If not this could explain the differences with official documentation.

Comment: Ok perhaps it's not official, but I installed it via anaconda. See link: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/keras-gpu. Looks to up to date.

Comment: In your link it says version 2.2.4, and last uploaded 6 months and 7 days ago, its not up to date at all. Don't forget that you claimed to use version 2.3.1